# email module in java?

Tags: java

Please suggest me the best email module in Java for sending e-mails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To further simplify the usage of JavaMail you can use [Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/). Take a look at the *Commons Email User Guide* there. From the webpage:

"Commons Email aims to provide a API for sending email. It is built on top of the Java Mail API, which it aims to simplify."

Answer (score 10):

[JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), included in the Java EE development kit, or downloadable as an extension for Java SE.

You can start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javamail) (Wikipedia).

However, there is no such thing as a universal "best" method, we can only make suggestions, the right choice for your needs is up to you.